# Determine the total size of a buffer in byte

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, sizeof

I am learning C and have this question. Suppose I declare the following buffer:

```
int n=100, dim=5;
double *buf = calloc(n * dim, sizeof(double));
```

How do I know **the total size** of this buffer that is declared in memory (in byte)? I use the following way but I am not sure if it is logically correct: `int buf_size_in_byte= (n)* sizeof(double);`

Comment: `buf_size_in_byte` should be type `size_t`, and it is: `size_t buf_size_in_byte = sizeof(double) * n * dim;`, or better: `size_t buf_size_in_byte = sizeof *buf * n * dim;`

Comment: @DavidBowling Thank you very much

Comment: Idea: Use `buf = calloc(n * dim, sizeof *buf);`, then no need to know the type  `buf` points to for the `calloc()` call.  Easier to write, review and update.

Answer (score 4):

The first parameter to [`calloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) is the number of objects and the second parameter is the size of each object. The total allocation size is the product of those two values. In your case that's `n * dim * sizeof(double)`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something:

buf itself is always just going to be sizeof (double *).

But the amount of memory you're allocating is going to be n * dim * sizeof(double).

free(buf) should still know exactly how much and which memory to deallocate when you're done with it however...

Comment: `double *` is what? (a pointer). You are correct (assuming your `itself` is `buf`), `buf` (or any pointer) will always be `sizeof (a pointer)` (generally 4-bytes on x86 or 8-bytes on x86_64). You are allocating a block of memory of whatever size is required to contain your data. (It's up to you). Yes `free` knows. How? It is your responsibility to *preserve a pointer to the start of* `buf`. If you do that, `free (buf);` knows what to free...